# Getting child products via rest/V1/configurable-products/(sku)/children

Tags: rest, api, magento, postman

On Magento 2.3.1 we need to get all products + child products from a certain SKU via the REST API. My problem is that child products are only loaded if I use the storefront url in the API call - Not if I use the main install url.

Why is the response from the main store domain empty?

To get main configurable products:

https://(main-store-domain)/rest/V1/products?fields=items[sku,name]&searchCriteria[pageSize]=1000

and

https://(store-view-domain)/rest/V1/products?fields=items[sku,name]&searchCriteria[pageSize]=1000

Both of the above works fine.

To get child variants:

https://(main-store-domain)/rest/V1/configurable-products/(sku)/children (Gives an empty response)

https://(store-view-domain)/rest/V1/configurable-products/(sku)/children (Gives me the child products)

I would expect both /rest/V1/configurable-products/(sku)/children to give me the list of child products

Comment: For me as well,  I got an empty response. @Jakob did you figure it out , why ?